# How to optimize loops that iterate massive dictionaries, with different value sizes?

Tags: python-2.7, loops, dataframe, dictionary, list-comprehension

This is my first post here, I hope someone can help me with this.

I have a massive dictionary called 'hello' (>2 Million Keys). This dictionary has values with different sizes (some are lists, others are just a single value). I have to iterate through the whole dictionary to get the following values:

```
portfolios = {k:v for k,v in hello.items() if '.some_list' in k}
hello_deltas = {k:v for k,v in hello.items() if '/delta[' or '/fast_spot[' or '/composite_delta_fx[' in k}

hello_before = {k:v for k,v in hello_deltas.items() if '_0_result' in k}
some_list_before = {}

for some_list in portfolios.values():

    for some in some_list:

        a = [i for i in hello_before.keys() if str(some) in i]

        if len(a) != 0:

            some_list_before[some] = a



hello_after = {k:v for k,v in hello_deltas.items() if '_1_result' in k}
some_list_after = {}

for some_list in portfolios.values():

    for some in some_list:

        a = [i for i in hello_after.keys() if str(some) in i]

        if len(a) != 0:

            some_list_after[some] = a
```

I already thought about this a lot, and accelerated it to a mega combo of comprehension dictionaries. HOWEVER, that is not enough.

I also tried to do everything in pandas dataframes but since the sizes of the values of the dictionary are not the same, i can't build a dataframe!

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use functions to avoid redundancy:

```
def before_after(hello, result):
    """result = '_0_result' (before) or '_1_result' (after)"""
    portfolios = {k:v for k,v in hello.items() if '.some_list' in k}
    hello_deltas = {k:v for k,v in hello.items() if '/delta[' or '/fast_spot[' or '/composite_delta_fx[' in k}
    hello_before_after = {k:v for k,v in hello_deltas.items() if result in k}
    some_list_before_after = {}
    for some_list in portfolios.values():
        for some in some_list:
            a = [i for i in hello_before_after.keys() if str(some) in i]
            if len(a) != 0:
                some_list_before_after[some] = a
    return some_list_before_after
```

Then before diving in list comprehensions, look at the code: you are building an intermediate dictionary but you could use a generator:

```
portfolios_lists = (v for k,v in hello.items() if '.some_list' in k)
for some_list in portfolios_lists:
    for some in some_list:
        ...
```

Or, better:

```
portfolios_somes = (s for k,v in hello.items() for s in v if '.some_list' in k)
for some in portfolios_somes:
    ...
```

You use only keys from `hello_deltas`:

```
hello_deltas_before_after = [k for k in hello.keys() if result in k and ('/delta[' or '/fast_spot[' or '/composite_delta_fx[' in k)]
```

Note: with a function you might think that you will test if `'/delta[' or '/fast_spot[' or '/composite_delta_fx[' in k` twice: one for `before` and one for `after`. Actually, this is not true: you first test if `result in k` (ie `'_0_result' in k` or `'_0_result' in k`) and *then* make the expensive test.

The code now looks like:

```
def before_after(hello, result):
    portfolios_somes = (s for k,v in hello.items() for s in v if '.some_list' in k)
    hello_deltas_before_after = [k for k in hello.keys() if result in k and ('/delta[' or '/fast_spot[' or '/composite_delta_fx[' in k)]
    some_list_before_after = {}
    for some in portfolios_somes:
        a = [i for i in hello_deltas_before_after if str(some) in i]
        if len(a) != 0:
            some_list_before_after[some] = a
    return some_list_before_after
```

Now, the dict omprehension:

```
some_list_before_after = {
    some: a 
    for some in portfolios_somes 
    for a in ([i for i in hello_deltas_before_after if str(some) in i], ) 
    if a}
```

The one element tuple is a trick to compute `a` only once. Full code (not tested):

```
def before_after(hello, result):
    portfolios_somes = (s for k, v in hello.items() for s in v if '.some_list' in k)
    hello_deltas_before_after = [k for k in hello.keys() if result in k and ('/delta[' or '/fast_spot[' or '/composite_delta_fx[' in k)]
    return {
        some: a 
        for some in portfolios_somes 
        for a in ([i for i in hello_deltas_before_after if str(some) in i], ) 
        if a}
```

This should be faster than the original version, but the problem has a (very roughly) O(n^2) time complexity and you won't get tour result in a second. Try it on a subset of the original data (e.g. `hello_short = dict(itertools.islice(hello.items(), 1000))`).